# Clojure: Integer value ending with "N"

Tags: clojure

I have read about `(*')` function in clojure.

```
(*' 1234567890 9876543210)



Result: ;;=> 12193263111263526900N
```

I tried to execute this below

```
(*' 4535353535345345345 5675675675675675677 4564564646456645)

Result: ;;=> 117497352037570255927282105564555048448707485315089425N
```

What is "N" here? Is it symbol for Infinite? and the output is which type Bigdecimal or any other type?

Comment: N is a modifier for `clojure.lang.BigInt` easily seen with `type`: `(type 1N)` => `clojure.lang.BigInt`, `(type 1M)` => `java.math.BigDecimal`, `(type 1)` => `java.lang.Long`

Comment: @leetwinski Very cute and quick understandable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(class (*' 4535353535345345345 5675675675675675677 4564564646456645))
```

is `clojure.lang.BigInt` and Clojure prints it like this:

```
;; src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj
(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.BigInt [b, ^Writer w]
  (.write w (str b))
  (.write w "N"))
```

so the `N` is just a note to let you know what type of integer it realy is.

This does not mean, though, you have to put `N` in the end to let Clojure know what kind of integer it is.